# Xamarin C# - How to reference a resource file programatically from a variable

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, imageview

I'm using Xamarin(C#) and trying to access the files in my Resources/drawable folder so that I can fill an ImageView with that picture. I have all the names of these resources(which are .png files) stored in an array and would like to loop through it to access each one.

I know you can access one file using Resource.Drawable.whateverTheNameIs but I don't want to hard code in the name, I want to be able to get it from a string variable. Is this possible? I tried the GetDrawables method but it's not finding it, and it also says its deprecated so I'd prefer the current way to do it.

Here's the exact code:

```
        ImageView daButton = row.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.theButtonThing);
        Drawable d = myContext.Resources.GetDrawable(myContext.Resources.GetIdentifier(mItems[position], "button", myContext.PackageName));

        daButton.SetImageDrawable(d);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can find resource Id this way, it works for me:

```
int resID = Resources.GetIdentifier(mDrawableName, "drawable", PackageName);
```